# How to create new table from .CSV file with duplicate fields in Sequel Pro

Tags: sql, csv

I am trying to create new table via CSV import and I am receiving this error message: An error occurred while trying to add the new table

```
CREATE TABLE `customers_type_risk` (
    `User ID` VARCHAR(255), 
    `Company ID` VARCHAR(255), 
    `Country` VARCHAR(255), 
    `Tag` VARCHAR(255), 
    `UTM Campaign` VARCHAR(255), 
    `UTM Content` VARCHAR(255), 
    `UTM Medium` VARCHAR(255), 
    `UTM Source` VARCHAR(255), 
    `UTM Term` VARCHAR(255), 
    `android_app` VARCHAR(255), 
    `ios_app` VARCHAR(255), 
    `OS Condition` VARCHAR(255), 
    `Plan` VARCHAR(255), 
    `Company tag` VARCHAR(255), 
    `Active users` VARCHAR(255), 
    `UTM Source` VARCHAR(255), 
    `UTM Medium` VARCHAR(255), 
    `UTM Campaign` VARCHAR(255), 
    `UTM Term` VARCHAR(255), 
    `UTM Content` VARCHAR(255), 
    `Is NGO` VARCHAR(255), 
    `subscription_expires_at (CEST)` VARCHAR(255), 
    `subscription_cycle` VARCHAR(255), 
    `At Least One User with iOS / Android App` INT(11), 
    `Company Type` VARCHAR(255), 
    `Days Till Expiration` INT(11), 
    `Risk of Loosing` VARCHAR(255)) ENGINE=CSV DEFAULT CHARACTER SET `utf8`.

MySQL said: Duplicate column name 'UTM Source'
```

I do not understand why it returns error **Duplicate column name 'UTM Source'** because I have already created very similar table which has also contained duplicated 'UTM Source', 'UTM Medium', 'UTM Camapign' fields. I did everything the same. In this new .CSV table are just some new fields `Company Type`, `Days Till Expiration`,`Risk of Loosing`

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I don't think you can have exactly same 2 column names in the same table

Comment: it is weird but I am pretty sure, somehow I managed to import another .CSF file where are duplicate column name 'UTM Source'... but when I double-checked I see that there is just one field in Sequel Pro table...in source .CSV file it's duplicate

Comment: Of course you can't have duplicate column names in a table. Which column would you get If you execute `SELECT "UTM Source" FROM customers_type_risk`? And which column should be used in a join? If it's duplicated in your source file, you'll still have to give them different names in your database table

Comment: May be there is an additional space or any other character in either

Comment: And please don't ask the same question [twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62967623/how-to-solve-error-message-while-creating-new-table-via-csv-import-in-sequel-pr)

Comment: Sorry, I asked it twice just because in the other question I did not get the full error message and I was not sure if it same issue...anyways, I solved it. I merged the columns and did import afterwards. Thanks